# Structure member alignment with _Alignas

Tags: c, standards, c11

I was wondering about the following: is the new `_Alignas` alignment
specifier in C11 applicable to structure members?

I've always assumed that much, but a thorough reading of the N1570
public draft seems to indicate that an *alignment-specifier* cannot
appear in a *specifier-qualifier-list*, which is where I'd expect it
to be, if it were supported. I've read the grammar a couple of times
but can't figure out how `_Alignas` is supposed to be permitted in
a structure member declaration.

However, it seems to me that the intent of the standard is that
`_Alignas` should be applicable to structure members as the paragraph
on `_Alignas` (§ 6.7.5) states that "an alignment attribute shall not
be specified in a declaration of [...] a bit-field". Given that
the term "bit-field" is defined in § 6.7.2.1 to be a structure
member (precise wording: "such a member is called a *bit-field*"),
I had always interpreted that sentence to implicitly mean alignment
specifiers were allowed for non-bit-field members.

Checking against existing implementations shows that both Clang 3.0
and GCC 4.7 support `_Alignas` on structure members without
complaining (with `-pedantic`). The Clang source code reproduces the
same grammar from N1570, except `Parser::ParseSpecifierQualifierList`
allows alignment specifiers; the function does contain a TODO element,
though, that reads:

```
/// TODO: diagnose attribute-specifiers and alignment-specifiers.
```

The GCC C parser code appears to be similar, i.e. even though it quotes
the standard grammar, it allows alignment specifiers in
specifier-qualifier lists.

I've also checked the list of known defects, as well as comp.lang.c
and comp.std.c, to see if the topic had been raised there but it
doesn't appear to be the case. Hence, my question: are alignment
specifiers supposed to be allowed on structure members?

EDIT: The relevant grammar rules are:

```
// Compare this...
(6.7) declaration-specifiers:
           storage-class-specifier declaration-specifiers_opt
           type-specifier declaration-specifiers_opt
           type-qualifier declaration-specifiers_opt
           function-specifier declaration-specifiers_opt
           // This seems to be the only place that mentions
           // alignment-specifier on the rhs of a rule.
           alignment-specifier declaration-specifiers_opt

(6.7.2.1) struct-or-union-specifier:
           struct-or-union identifier_opt { struct-declaration-list }
           struct-or-union identifier

(6.7.2.1) struct-declaration-list:
           struct-declaration
           struct-declaration-list struct-declaration

(6.7.2.1) struct-declaration:
           specifier-qualifier-list struct-declarator-list_opt ;
           static_assert-declaration

// ...to this.
(6.7.2.1) specifier-qualifier-list:
           type-specifier specifier-qualifier-list_opt
           type-qualifier specifier-qualifier-list_opt
           // Missing alignment-specifier specifier-qualifier-list_opt?

(6.7.5) alignment-specifier:
          _Alignas ( type-name )
          _Alignas ( constant-expression )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Section 6.7.5, p 6, clearly specifies that this also concerns alignment of members

> The alignment requirement of the declared object or member is taken to
>   be the specified alignment.

So the intended semantic is that one. If as you say the formal specification of the grammar misses that bit (I didn't check), this is a defect, and you should report it.

**Edit:** Looking into the grammar, it seems to me that an addition of `alignment-specifier` in 6.7.2.1 is missing in the cases of `specifier-qualifier-list`, and also that a textual explanation in para 14 would be in order.

Comment: I see --- I missed that bit (or maybe reread it too many times that it somehow slipped through when I finally posted to SO); it was my understanding, also, that it was intended to apply to members. But then I started checking around Clang and GCC and got confused. If you have the time, could you also take a look at the grammar? I might have missed something as well... (since I did miss the passage your're quoting, which makes the intent quite clear indeed) Thanks.

Comment: So it wasn't just my seeing things... Thank you for taking the time to look at the issue. About reporting a defect, AFAIK the standard committee is a rather hermetic body and a bit intimidating for some random guy on the Internet like me. But if the error is real, I'm sure somebody important will notice it sooner or later, starting with the various implementors. :) (The TODO in the Clang code seems to indicate that at least somebody noticed the absence of `alignment-specifier` in `specifier-qualifier-list`.)

Comment: It looks like `_Noreturn` also ought to be allowed in a `specifier-qualifier-list` for function-pointer struct members, because it is allowed in ordinary (non-struct-member) function-pointer declarations.