# _Alignas for struct members using clang & C11

Tags: c, compiler-construction, struct, c11

I'm having some trouble with -Wpadded using C11 and structs.

I've already read [Structure member alignment with _Alignas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10676827/structure-member-alignment-with-alignas), and I looked in the clang docs and saw that it IS supported now.

Also, I'm using a very new version of clang that I built from trunk recently.

```
$ clang --version
clang version 3.3 (trunk 175473)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
```

The problem I'm running into is this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdalign.h>

struct foo{
   void* a;
   int b;
};

int main() {
   struct foo instance;

   instance.a = NULL;
   instance.b = 2;

   return 0;
}
```

Which throws me this warning:

```
$ clang -Weverything -std=c11 t.c 
t.c:4:8: warning: padding size of 'struct foo' with 4 bytes to alignment boundary [-Wpadded]
struct foo{
       ^
1 warning generated.
```

Now isn't this what `_Alignas` is for? I tried putting it before the int member declaration, like so:

```
struct foo{
   void* a;
   _Alignas(void*) int b;
};
```

But the same warning remains. I also tried putting the _Alignas in various places, to no avail. What am I missing here?

I know I could just ignore this particular warning and I understand why padding is important, so I'm not interested in workarounds or explanations about what padding is. I want to know how to change my C in a portable, standards conformant way so that the warning is no longer emitted.

Comment: The warning tells you that there were four bytes of padding added to the structure in order to have the `void*` member properly aligned in an array (so that the size of the structure is a multiple of `void*`'s alignment requirement). Telling the compiler that the `int` member should be aligned as a `void*` doesn't change that, there are still four bytes of padding needed.

Comment: @DanielFischer could I quiet this with a dummy bit-field?

Comment: I would be extremely surprised if you couldn't. If you add a field `int dummy:26;` or so, the natural size would be `8 + 4 + 4` bytes. (On the typical 64-bit platform with 32-bit `int`s)

Comment: @DanielFischer cool it worked, but with dummy:32. Isn't there a more portable way to statically determine this number and then add in the field silently, perhaps with the preprocessor?

Comment: (running these tests on an AMD Opteron 6174)

Comment: Portable is hairy. You could determine whether a dummy is necessary to silence the warning in a configuration step, but I don't know how you could portably find the size of a `void*` using only the preprocessor. You could make it an array, `struct foo { void* a; int b[(sizeof(void*) + sizeof(int) - 1) / sizeof(int)]; };` and only use `b[0]`, but that's ugly too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-Weverything` prints all diagnostic messages required by C as well as some diagnostics not required by C. The diagnostic that is printed here is not required by C: its purpose is informative and your program is already strictly conforming. C says an implementation is free to produce additional diagnostic messages as long as it does not fail to translate the program.

Comment: So what's the motivation for this particular diagnostic? That I could potentially change the struct somehow so that if I had arrays of it there wouldn't be a performance problem because the struct was misaligned in memory?

Comment: To inform you that the structure object may take more bytes than you could expect?